# make playlist from a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

I have music website and it has a custom post type named Songs and want to do something that users be able to make playlist from musics of my website, name it and share it with other users exactly like spotify.com
I searched the web but didn't find anything.
Please introduce me a plugin or give me an idea
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar.

My approach was to run a query on the post type.

I stored all my song data (MP3 URL, track artist, etc.) in the post meta, then with JavaScript, users could store an object to local storage, session and or cookie, depending on how big the object was.

You can always set up an extra post type called *playlist* and store a sanitized object in the meta.

Comment: thank for your answer songs data are stored in post meta already but as i want users be able to save and share their playlist with other too i think dealing with session and cookies is not a good solution also i'm agree with set up a new post type but i'm looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: If you want users to share you'd do the following.
Use javascript on the client side to create a playlist array.
Save that playlist array to a playlist post type in the post meta.
You can use wp_insert_post() to create a new playlist post and return the user the url. then on the page you'd grab that array and display it as you wish.

Comment: Hi i started new post type setup and i have some sort of questions
first: Make a public post type and let everyone to publish post on it doesn't reduce my website security?
second: I have to let users to upload their playlist cover into wordpress media library does it cause hackers to hack my website with shell or something like that?